# Highcharts Ajax Json not displaying Chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to use the ajax line chart and I've created the following but it's not displaying anything.

What i am trying to achieve is to display the page views for the last 30 days. Hence my Json encode shows [date,page views]

I want the dates to display at the bottom horizontally, and the number of page counts on the vertical axis.

When i load the page, there's no error but it displays blank.

**Update: I've updated the JSON data but I do not understand what kind of order it needs to be sorted by, since the data now is [A,B] and I sorted it ascending order of A.**

> {"data":[[1476374400000,143],[1476288000000,190],[1476201600000,108],[1476115200000,145],[1476028800000,125],[1475942400000,15],[1475856000000,18],[1475769600000,26],[1475683200000,31],[1475596800000,42],[1475510400000,19],[1475424000000,34],[1475337600000,46],[1475251200000,34],[1475164800000,46],[1475078400000,34],[1474992000000,33],[1474905600000,39],[1474819200000,52],[1474732800000,47],[1474646400000,60],[1474560000000,40],[1474473600000,52],[1474387200000,51],[1474300800000,70],[1474214400000,69],[1474128000000,64],[1474041600000,45],[1473955200000,47],[1473868800000,44]],"name":"www.example.com"}

And then by following the codes on highcharts website I got this.

```
<head>

    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.src.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <!-- Additional files for the Highslide popup effect -->
    <!-- Additional files for the Highslide popup effect -->
    <script src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/static/highslide-full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/static/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/static/highslide.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

// Get the CSV and create the chart
        $.getJSON('https://www.micro.sg/json/', function (data) {

            $('#container').highcharts({

                data: {
                    json: data
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Daily visits at www.highcharts.com'
                },

                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: Google Analytics'
                },

                xAxis: {
                    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one week
                    tickWidth: 0,
                    gridLineWidth: 1,
                    labels: {
                        align: 'left',
                        x: 3,
                        y: -3
                    }
                },

                yAxis: [{ // left y axis
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    labels: {
                        align: 'left',
                        x: 3,
                        y: 16,
                        format: '{value:.,0f}'
                    },
                    showFirstLabel: false
                }, { // right y axis
                    linkedTo: 0,
                    gridLineWidth: 0,
                    opposite: true,
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    labels: {
                        align: 'right',
                        x: -3,
                        y: 16,
                        format: '{value:.,0f}'
                    },
                    showFirstLabel: false
                }],

                legend: {
                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: 20,
                    floating: true,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },

                tooltip: {
                    shared: true,
                    crosshairs: true
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function (e) {
                                    hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                                        pageOrigin: {
                                            x: e.pageX || e.clientX,
                                            y: e.pageY || e.clientY
                                        },
                                        headingText: this.series.name,
                                        maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + ':<br/> ' +
                                        this.y + ' visits',
                                        width: 200
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        marker: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'All visits',
                    lineWidth: 4,
                    marker: {
                        radius: 4
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'New visitors'
                }]
            });
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your code. The first thing is you do not have to use data module to load json - actually it does nothing with the data - so your chart is empty.
You should put the data into series property - remember one thing that it requires array, not an object, so in this case it should be like this (such options include 3 series, which 2 of them have no data):

```
series: [series, {
      name: 'All visits',
      lineWidth: 4,
      marker: {
        radius: 4
      },
    }, {
      name: 'New visitors'
    }]
```

The other problem is that the data needs to be sorted. Preferable way is to do this on server side but, of course, you can sort this in the browser.

```
  series.data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[0]-b[0];
  });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ojg90mmg/1/

Comment: Thank you I got it sorted out with your answer, however I'm not clear on sorting out the array. Please see update on my question on my new json data.

Comment: I'm using PHP so if it can be sorted out when I'm generating the JSON data from mysql, i will just do it from server side.